# How do I use Bootstrap's validation states?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a login form that uses Bootstrap. The email and password input controls are default Bootstrap controls. But I want to change the password box to Bootstrap's 'input with error' [validation state](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation). I know I'm supposed to get it's parent div to include the has-error class but I want that to happen only if the password is incorrect (which I realize only from a jQuery post response). So how can I indicate an incorrect password using a validation state?

Here's my code anyway:

```
<div id="pass" class="form-group">
            <label id="lbPass" style="display:none;"  for="pwd">Password</label>
            <input tabindex="2" type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd" id="pwd" placeholder="Password">
            <label style="visibility:hidden;" id="wc" class="control-label" for="pwd" style="margin: 3px 0 5px 0;">Wrong Credentials</label>
            <span class="help-block" style="font-size:12px; font padding:2px;"><a href="" >Forgot password?</a></span>
        </div>
```

**EDIT (SOLVED):**

@MattD pointed out in the comments that I should use jQuery's addClass() to add the 'has-error' class to the password div. It solved the problem.

Here's the code I used to change the class:

```
.fail(function(){

        $('#pass').addClass('has-error');

        document.getElementById('wc').style.visibility = 'visible';
    })
```

Comment: How are you running/handling your validation?

Comment: By using a validator, here's one: http://bootstrapvalidator.com/ read the docs

Comment: @MattD I use $.post() to a .php file which returns an error if the credentials are incorrect. I'm using it only to build a front-end prototype. So depending on the response from the $.post() function, I use a JS window.location.replace() to redirect to a new page if successful. I understand that's not real validation but like I said, it's just a UI prototype.

Comment: @Christina I did check that out, but figured there's got to be a way to use Bootstrap's native validation states. Else, how would these validation states be useful out of the box.. Sorry, I'm new to web dev so don't have deep knowledge of Bootstrap.

Comment: Well if you're handling whether you send them to the new page with JS, in the event it comes back as failing to meet validation, couldn't you then use JS to add that class to the `form-group` div? If success, redirect, else `$('#pass').addClass('has-error');`

Comment: There is no validation with Bootstrap. They provided the classes, you provide the js

Comment: @MattD yes! I tried that but it didn't work. :/ Does the element need to be reloaded to incorporate the new has-error class' formatting?

Comment: @MattD I've edited the question with the code I used to change the class.

Comment: Should have to reload the element. http://jsfiddle.net/bp6orakz/

Comment: That should read shouldn't, not should.

Comment: Guess I'll post it as an answer then? :P

Comment: @MattD Yes please :D
And looks like I don't have enough reputation to vote, damn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be as simple as adding the class via jQuery based on what you've provided. Should the validation fail, add the class.

**jQUery:**

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    if ( 1 > 2 ) {
        //whatevs...
    } else {
        $('#pass').addClass('has-error');
    }
});
```

The 1 > 2 bit is simply to get into the else condition.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bp6orakz/)**

Comment: Why not any other statement to evaluate to false? I chose what I chose.

Comment: Why not less defensive... Alright why not stop here.